# What's the safest way to swap an SSD (RAID 10)?

Tags: raid, supermicro, lsi, megacli

I have machines (4x 2 TB SSDs, Hardware RAID 10 via LSI 9265-8i cards) and occasionally need to swap an SSD - for example if it fails.

I'm curious to hear what people consider to be the safest approach in swapping failed drives whilst a server is online and booted into the OS.

One thing that unfortunately won't work is enabling drive LED (megali PdLocate) for the good drives (leaving the bad drive without a light, and the obvious one to replace). The SuperMicro casing seems to mean these aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is setup for RAID 10 with "Hotswap" (Meaning it has a back plane for quick HDD removal) you should be able to safely remove at least one of the drives at at all times unless the array is rebuilding. A properly built server will usually have the Port 0(Drive 1) HDD on the left and port 3 (Drive 4) on the right, that is one way to identify. Either way when you figure it out make sure to label as such.